# Cannot boot into live session from USB on Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows, live-usb, asus

I'm having a bit of an issue trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on ASUS G51Jx.

Whenever I change the boot order to USB first, I get a strange occurrence. My screen blinks and I see part of the Ubuntu background combined with my Windows 10 log-in screen.

When I shutdown the computer and remove the USB Windows 10 boots up just fine so it doesn't appear to break anything.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?:

- Try another USB or flash to USB again.
- Use this? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
- Redownload .iso and try again. Maybe it got corrupt or something.

Comment: I've used the USB on another laptop and it worked just fine.

Comment: Check bios then maybe? try turning of secure boot. Also have you tried to press F-something like F12 on my thinkpad, and choose USB, instead of changing the boot order.

Comment: I just got an Idea..  Try with nomodeset. Before you press "try ubuntu now" you should be able to change kernel boot or something like that. You should get a long command, add nomodeset and press enter to boot. 

Try this after: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu
a

Comment: @JoakinKoed That worked thanks. Now I'm having a separate issue where ubuntu is not recognizing my windows 10 install. It just sees it as free space.

Comment: Select manual or something like that (can't remember the correct name right now) during install, so you can see all the drives. It really should work.. Then you should be able to do it.

Comment: Even doing it manually doesn't show the partition. I know where the unallocated space is on my drive but I'm hesitant to make a partition when it only sees it all as free space. I can post images of what's happening if that would be better.

Comment: You should mark this as solved, and open a new question for that, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing Boot Order, You can directly boot from USB drive without affecting boot order. Look for the option before going into BIOS setup (It varies from system to system, so check it with your system and see what happens. Also try to install the Ubuntu on a different drive other than Windows.

I am also running Windows 10 with Ubuntu 15.10 (Wiley) on a two different drive. And I follow the above method.

Good Luck!

Comment: This worked. Now I'm having an issue with Ubuntu recognizing my windows install. It just sees my entire drive as free space. I only have one harddrive with this computer but i do have 20Gb unallocated space for ubuntu.

Comment: Choose **something else** while installation and make at least 3 partition "/ " (root), Swap and Home from 20 GB unallocated space. Do not make changes to other partition.

Comment: The issue is that it doesnt recognize the other partition. http://imgur.com/a/eQK6W GParted sees it as free space too

Comment: Is it necessary to use GParted? Because sometimes it may not work properly, I can confirm it. You have the option of creating partition with the default Ubuntu Installer. Right?  And one more thing - What Partition table do you have right now MBR or GPT?